# Find all the least squares solutions of Ax=b

Tags: matrices

Find all least squares solutions of  A **x** = **b**, where A =

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 3           \\[0.3em]
       -2 &-6          \\[0.3em]
       3 & 9
     \end{bmatrix}

and **b** = \begin{bmatrix}
       1           \\[0.3em]
       0          \\[0.3em]
       1
     \end{bmatrix}

and confirm that all
the solutions have the same error vector (and hence the same least squares error).
Compute the least-squares error.

The system that corresponds to the reduced row echelon form of the augmented matrix is $x_1 + 3x_2 =0, 0=1, 0=0 $ since the second equation cannot be solved the system is inconsistent

I'm not sure how to calculate the least squares solutions of A **x** = **b** because the inverse of $A^TA$ does not exist and so I can't solve the normal equations $A^TAx=A^Tb$ for x

Answer (score 2):

Even though $A^TA$ is singular, you *can* solve the normal equations. Note that, from a theoretical perspective, $A^Tb$ is in the column space (image) of $A^T$, and the column space of $A^TA$ is the same subspace — again, for emphasis, *always*.

Comment: Please would it be possible to explain how the normal equations can be solved?

Comment: Without inverses. Just solve with an augmented matrix, as you would any inhomogeneous system.

Comment: Please could you explain how i would go about finding the error in this case. Thanks

Comment: How do you usually find the error?

Answer (score 0):

You want to choose $x$ that minimizes in a least squares sense the error of $Ax = b$.  So you want to minimize $(Ax-b)^\intercal(Ax - b) = x^\intercal A^\intercal Ax - x^\intercal A^\intercal b - b^\intercal A x + b^\intercal b = x^\intercal A^\intercal Ax - 2 b^\intercal A x + b^\intercal b$.

At a local minimum the partial derivatives with respect to each element of $x$ will be 0.

So we want to solve $2A^\intercal A x - 2A^\intercal b = 0$, which is equivalent to $A^\intercal A x = A^\intercal b$.  Since $A^\intercal A$ is square, so we can try to invert it and solve $x = (A^\intercal A)^{-1}A^\intercal b$

That's a linear equation, so it only has one solution if it has any.  So there can only be one minimum.

Comment: Note that $A^\top A$ is *not* invertible in this case.